# Notepad++ 6.4.5 disable plugins update tab

Tags: windows-7, notepad++

How to disable Updates tab from Plugins i.e.

1. Launch the Notepad++ shortcut
2. Go to "Plugins"->"Plugin Manager" -> "Show Plugin Manager"
3. Under that there's an Updates tab.

Is there a way to disable or grey out this update tab from GUI itself?

Answer (score 2):

4. On Updates tab, there is a button "Settings" at the bottom - click to open Plugin Manager Settings and check off "Notify of plugin updates at startup".